# Add to FRONT of my PATH when installing Flutter

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, path, homebrew

i am styring to install Flutter and already installed Dart but now get this when I do: flutter doctor

Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dart/2.19.6/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside
your current Flutter SDK checkout at
/Users/xx/Documents/Development/flutter. Consider adding
/Users/xx/Documents/Development/flutter/bin to the front of
your path.

I already added as it recommends /Users/xx/Documents/Development/flutter/bin to my PATH - still it shows the same and I would love to resolve this. Maybe someone can help?

Thx already!

adding to PATH - that it then works

Comment: Did you do what it says in the title and add Flutter to the **front** of the PATH? As in before everything else? If you just stick it in the back of PATH, then it might pick up a Dart/Flutter version that you have saved elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `Users/{USERNAME}/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=/PATH/TO/FLUTTER/bin:$PATH
```

If the Error still appears, add the same to your `Users/{USERNAME}/.bash_profile`